# Forseeable issues with running phpMyadmin MySql and MySQL root installed on my machine

Tags: php, mysql, database, phpmyadmin, xampp

I installed MySQL on my machine (Desktop, Windows 10) and created an application that gets data from the database and displays it on the application. The application is not important at this time.

I then installed Xampp, with Apache,Mysql, and phpMyadmin. I am trying to learn how to take my database onto the web. The issue/problem I am having is that in order to access the phpMyadmin website I need to close my Mysql connection on my machine via the Task Manager in order to connect to phpMyadmin. Then in order to connect to the MySql on my machine so my application can access the database I need to Stop the MySql connection via the Xampp application.

This is just for development, for now, it is not for a project. Is it okay to keep opening and closing the Mysql connections like this?

I do believe the error is caused because they (machine MySQL and phpMyadmin MySQL) both run on the same port of 3306. Is there also a way to solve this?

Comment: two programs can't run on the same port, one will use 3306 and teh other something lloke 3307(but you can configure that inmy.conf) and wuith the different ports you can access bith databases from phpmyadmin

Comment: phpMyAdmin is a client and will not listen on port 3306. Your phpMyAdmin might use port 3306 to connect to MySQL, but won't listen or block that (or any other) port (depending on your connection settings; it might use a named pipe instead of TCP/IP). When you say you have to close the MySQL connection through Task Manager, what is the exact program you're forcing to close? What is the exact error message when it fails because you didn't close the program?